# Is there a built-in property or method in PowerShell/.NET to check if the XML one is working with has been modified?

Tags: .net, powershell

I've written a PowerShell script to make modifications to XML files, but since not every XML file needs to be updated I don't want to needlessly write to the file.  I'm currently setting a variable to `$true` when I've (or the script) made a modification:

```
[bool]$Modified = $false
[string]$PathToXML = $env:UserProfile + '\test.xml'
$XMLObject = New-Object XML
$XMLObject.Load($PathToXML)
If($XMLObject.property.otherproperty -ne 'Goldfish')
    {
        $XMLObject.property.otherproperty = 'Goldfish'
       [bool]$Modified = $true
    }
if($Modofied -eq $true) { $XMLObject.Save($PathToXML) }
```

But this got me wondering: Is there is a built-in property or method in PowerShell or .NET that would automatically track modifications to the already loaded XML object and return a boolean value which would indicate whether or not the already loaded XML object was modified?  Something like:

```
[string]$PathToXML = $env:UserProfile + '\test.xml'
$XMLObject = New-Object XML
$XMLObject.Load($PathToXML)
# Checking $XMLObject.IsChanged would return false
If($XMLObject.property.otherproperty -ne 'Goldfish')
    {
        $XMLObject.property.otherproperty = 'Goldfish'
        # A this point $XMLObject.IsChanged is now true
    }
if($XMLObject.IsChanged) { $XMLObject.Save($PathToXML) }
```

The closest example I can provide is the IsChanged property in the Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.Application class: Once you've deserialized the XML and make a change to any property, the `IsChanged` property is automatically updated from false to true.

Comment: What does "the XML" mean? XML is not linked to a file.

Comment: Modified by the script? Modified since a previous point-in-time?

Comment: I think I see what you mean; I updated the post in an attempt to clarify further.

Comment: `XML` is in fact an [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). Can't find any likely candidates (even the tracking events aren't going to help much here)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm so glad someone touched on events because that's kind of where my head was at.  Thanks for the expert guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do it like below.

```
If($XMLObject.property.otherproperty -ne 'Goldfish')
   {
       $XMLObject.property.otherproperty = 'Goldfish'
       $XMLObject.Save($PathToXML)
   }
```

Do the save inside the `if` statement.

Comment: I presume from their narrative that they have multiple modifications they *may* make. Their sample only performs one but I don't think it's indicative of the real script.

Comment: Since its an `if` statement, `Save` method can be at the end.

Comment: Yes, but not if the full script is `if(x) {y} if (u) {v} if (t) {s}` and they want to save at the end if any of `x`, `u` or `t` were true. Which tends to be the reason people will write "flag" code like is shown in the question in the first place.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you're correct: I have multiple edits to make hence the 'flag' code as you put it.

Comment: @PRASOONKARUNANV I could save it in the if statement as you suggested. 
 I suppose there's no harm in doing it that way although to be candid I feel more comfortable writing once vs up to 10 times depending on the edits I need to make.  Bottom line it sounds like the answer is no.